# Sendbird stay logged in on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, sendbird

So I've implemented SendBird in my website (I'm using the javascript version 3.0, the sendbird widget) and like it says in the README.md file, users have to log in every time the browser (the page) is refreshed. I wanted to change that and I read this in the readme file:

> you must implement an appropriate `event handler`

Now I think they mean the 'connection handler' which can be found in their documentation, [Sendbird connection event handler](https://docs.sendbird.com/javascript#event_handler).
But I don't know where I have to place this? Do I have to place that handler in one of their files or does it not matter where the code goes? And will that code work like that (with my appId in place of course) or do changes have to be made?